# setting href value to javascript variable on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the href value passed to a variable when the user clicks on the link from a particular class. This is what I have right now.

```
$(document).on('click',"a.show-notes",function{
    var $url = $(this).attr("href");
)};
```

This is not working for me though, and no value is being passed to the variable. I have also tried something like this, with no luck...

```
$("a.show-notes").on('click',function(){
    var $url = $(this).attr("href");
)};
```

I imagine that there is something obvious here that I am missing, but I've been starring at it for so long that my mind is fried.

Comment: The first code is a syntax error, the second should work as long as the element is static. Where are you trying to use this variable ?

Comment: Could you please try ".show-notes a" it will fix the code I think...

Comment: You're declaring "$url" *inside* the function, so it's *local* to that function. It'll be un-seeable outside the function.

Comment: Okay, there must be something else going on here. Does attr("href") return what is hard coded? My href is being generated by an embedded ruby variable. I wasn't thinking that this could be the issue though, because when I check the source code or inspect the link in my browser, I am seeing the desired href, of course.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments everybody. I'll come back to it tomorrow.

Answer (score 3):

Ensure you're setting those hooks after the DOM has loaded and those elements exist. Wrap them inside a $(document).ready function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a.show-notes").on('click',function(){
    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    console.log(url);
  });
});
```

Comment: This should work! One more thing you can try is testing the window.location.hash variable, which returns the hash-component of the current url.

Comment: I could be wrong but using `.on` *should* make the document.ready irrelevant.

Comment: The first version should work without doing this though

Comment: From jQuery spec: "Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on()" http://api.jquery.com/on/ so the delegated format (first alternative) would work without dom ready

Comment: In the first version, the handler is bound to document (just like the ready handler in your code)

Answer (score 1):

You have some syntax errors:

```
$(document).on('click',"a.show-notes",function(){
    var $url = $(this).attr("href");         //^missing parenthesis
    alert($url);
});
//^bad closing
```

Note: Also the $variable name convention is normally used only for jquery elements like:

```
var $element = $("li");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('a.show-notes').click(function(){
    var $url = $(this).attr('href');
});
```

The variable `$url` variable can be named however you like (`url`, `myLink`, etc.) but it is only visible inside the `click()` function. If you want to use it outside, create the variable before the `click()` function, and set it inside.